# How to have multiple consumer from one io.Reader?

Tags: stream, go

I am working on a small script which uses `bufio.Scanner` and `http.Request` as well as go routines to count words and lines in parallel.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    err := request("http://www.google.com")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // just keep main alive with sleep for now
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}

func request(url string) error {
    res, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    go scanLineWise(res.Body)
    go scanWordWise(res.Body)

    return err
}

func scanLineWise(r io.Reader) {
    s := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    s.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

    i := 0

    for s.Scan() {
        i++
    }

    fmt.Printf("Counted %d lines.\n", i)
}

func scanWordWise(r io.Reader) {
    s := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    s.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

    i := 0

    for s.Scan() {
        i++
    }

    fmt.Printf("Counted %d words.\n", i)
}
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/bodokaiser/4f32be93a753c4b67a80)

As more or less expected from streams `scanLineWise` will count a number while `scalWordWise` will count zero. This is because `scanLineWise` already reads everything from `req.Body`.

I would know like to know: **How to solve this elegantly?**

*My first thought was to build a struct which implements `io.Reader` and `io.Writer`. We could use `io.Copy` to read from `req.Body` and write it to the `writer`. When the scanners read from this writer then writer will copy the data instead of reading it. Unfortunately this will just collect memory over time and break the whole idea of streams...*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The options are pretty straightforward -- you either maintain the "stream" of data, or you buffer the body.

If you really do need to read over the body more then once sequentially, you need to buffer it somewhere. There's no way around that.

There's a number of way you could stream the data, like having the line counter output lines into the word counter (preferably through channels). You could also build a pipeline using `io.TeeReader` and `io.Pipe`, and supply a unique reader for each function.

```
...
pipeReader, pipeWriter := io.Pipe()
bodyReader := io.TeeReader(res.Body, pipeWriter)
go scanLineWise(bodyReader)
go scanWordWise(pipeReader)
...
```

That can get unwieldy with more consumers though, so you could use `io.MultiWriter` to multiplex to more `io.Readers`.

```
...
pipeOneR, pipeOneW := io.Pipe()
pipeTwoR, pipeTwoW := io.Pipe()
pipeThreeR, pipeThreeW := io.Pipe()

go scanLineWise(pipeOneR)
go scanWordWise(pipeTwoR)
go scanSomething(pipeThreeR)

// of course, this should probably have some error handling
io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(pipeOneW, pipeTwoW, pipeThreeW), res.Body)
...
```

Comment: I never thought of using `io.Pipe()` like that, +1 for teaching me something new!

Comment: @JimB How would this look like if I have three consumers? Wouldn't one reader be there as overhead?

Comment: for 3 or more, you would have to make more Pipes and split the bodyReader again each time, but that starts to get messy. I'll put a MultiWriter approach in the answer too for this case. I would prefer though, to use channels and break down the stream progressively if possible.

Comment: If you're using this with synchronization mechanisms (e.g. `sync.WaitGroup`) to wait for all goroutines to finish, don't forget to call `pipe<X>W.Close()` after `io.Copy` or you will get a deadlock since the pipe readers are still waiting in their routines.

Answer (score 4):

You could use channels, do the actual reading in your `scanLineWise` then pass the lines to `scanWordWise`, for [example](http://play.golang.org/p/EwXs1Ep_XX):

```
func countLines(r io.Reader) (ch chan string) {
    ch = make(chan string)
    go func() {
        s := bufio.NewScanner(r)
        s.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

        cnt := 0

        for s.Scan() {
            ch <- s.Text()
            cnt++
        }
        close(ch)
        fmt.Printf("Counted %d lines.\n", cnt)
    }()

    return
}

func countWords(ch <-chan string) {
    cnt := 0
    for line := range ch {
        s := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(line))
        s.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
        for s.Scan() {
            cnt++
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Counted %d words.\n", cnt)
}

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader(body)
    ch := countLines(r)
    go countWords(ch)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: Channels may create unnecessary contention here. io package may become more useful. Design-wise channels may become more useful though.